# IE - Angular's json response contains unicode character that removed additional characters. Invalid JSON

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, unicode, character-encoding, httpresponse

I have a http response that has a name that contains a unicode character (ex. Müller).
In IE11, I'm getting an error that says "Invalid Character" because it seems that in IE11 the whole http response is read as a string in angular's http response, and it tries to parse this string into JSON (instead of already in JSON format). But in the JSON string it looks something like this:
    `...,\"lastName\":\"M�}],\"id\":1,...`

The problem is that part of the last name got stripped, and now the lastName value has a missing close quote. I don't mind that its displaying the diamond question mark, its just completely breaking the response now.

In chrome it works fine, as the data is actually returned as a JSON object, unlike IE11 where it returned as a string, and then tries to convert to JSON in  the default transform response functions.

The request is in application/json charset: utf-8 format. 
The response is in application/json format.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Edit: In IE11's network response body, it shows it correctly as "Müller" in the JSON format.

Edit: It seems like its eating up the first 5 characters after the `ü` when returning the response. (ex. Mülleraa will look like `...\"M�a\"...` where the closing quote is back with an additional 'a' char)

Comment: >Edit: In IE11's network response body, it shows it correctly as "Müller" in the JSON format.

>Edit: It seems like its eating up the first 5 characters after the ü when returning the response. (ex. Mülleraa will look like ...\"M�a\"... where the closing quote is back with an additional 'a' char)


Do you mean in the IE11 's network response body, it shows the data correctly, and when you try to parse the json string, it will show the invalid Character error?

Comment: I create a sample using the [following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU7R9.png), the response object also contains "Mülleraa", but it works well on IE browser (version: 11.17134.1.0), the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4klLv.png). So, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In your request, add:

```
headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  "Accept-Charset":"charset=utf-8"
},
```

Comment: my request needs to be in application/json, but the problem isnt with the url, its with the reading of the response in IE11 within angularjs.

Comment: Tried it and still the same problem.